# how to implement an automatic packaging system for a java desktop application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, desktop-application

A couple of years ago I started an open source project that used javaFX + jdk8 to create a desktop application for windows. A few months ago I decided to continue improving the project and make it a little more professional and easy to work on. For that, the first thing I did was migrate to JDK 11 and include Maven. Right now my project starts up and works fine in the IDE. But I am finding it very difficult to compile and package it.

A few months ago, I created another desktop application with javascript and electron. I loved that with a couple of commands, the application compiled and packaged automatically for windows, mac, and linux.

I am trying to do something similar with my java application. That is, use some tool that allows you to make all this ready and automated. I don't know if Maven has these features or if I need to use other tools. I know there are solutions like "launch4j", but what I'm trying to do is create a system that does everything with a couple of commands. The idea is that anyone who downloads the project will have it easy to package the applications.

So the question would be, now that I have a working project, what system do you recommend using to package my project? Which way should I go?

Comment: You should have a look at the native image support of GraalVM. With this nice feature you can create native executables für Windows, macOS, Linux, …
I highly recommend this recording from Devoxx 2019: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKrR4PGTgoc

Comment: There is a nice summary of jpackage in the [JEP 392: Packaing tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392) documentation. Also, wiverson put together a great [example packaging project](https://github.com/wiverson/maven-jpackage-template) to illustrate packaging using maven+jpackage+javafx+Java 16+wix, which would appear to be the closest thing to what you are requesting.

Comment: As others have noted, one tool is `jpackage` (incubating Java 14/15, stable Java 16). It has a [user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A). Unfortunately that tool can only make packages for the operating system you're invoking it on. But if you want ready-made packages for Windows, MacOS, and Linux then I believe you can use CI/CD (e.g. on GitHub, GitLab, etc.) to automatically create packages/releases.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go with this is use the jpackage tool which is made exactly for this. Here is a tutorial which explains how to use that with Maven. https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX